# Why does Pilgrim kill this character?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-punisher-2017

In *Marvel's The Punisher* season 2 episode 3 after the shootout at Larkville county

> Marlene suggests going after them again and Pilgrim kills her.

**Why did he kill her?** Was that because she messed up (and more than one time) or he disapproved her plan or what?

Comment: Just your typical, "No, you won't ever fail me again [because I'm a bad guy and I'm gonna kill you]" situation. He also didn't think it was going to be as difficult as it seemed to get [what he was there for] and figured one less minion would not be a problem... which in retrospect he was probably right anyway.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no evidence to support, but I think Odin1806 has it correct, this was a fairly obvious "you failed again, this was the last time" scenario. Marlene I believe talks about not failing again after her first failure to help emphasize her death when it comes without needing further explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In *Fight or Flight* Marlena Olin played by [Teri Reeves](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3117202/?ref_=tt_cl_t10) was part of the Pilgrim's hit squad sent in to kill Frank and recover Rachel, who Frank was using as bait. Because Frank had planned and set up in the room adjacent to his own, the hit squad was reverse-ambushed and Frank shot Marlena in the knee, taking her captive.

Later in [*Trouble the Water*](https://www.superherohype.com/tv/433227-the-punisher-season-2-episode-3-recap) they were with Sheriff Hardin. Marlena offered to spare Hardin from Pilgrim's assault if he would let her go free. This is the mistake which got her killed, because it gave Hardin an opportunity to plan for Pilgrim's atack. Pilgrim knew Marlena sold him out when Hardin tried his plan, so he shot her for her betrayal.